# Limit users in WordPress to access defined post with custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, user-controls, custom-post-type

I building one plugin what need to allow admins to exclude users from reading some special contents using post ID and custom post type.

Generaly, if some post have ID `99` with custom post type `lesions` and admin choose that to exclude, user get 404 if go on direct link and also not see that post in list.

NOTE: I don't need to made loop, I need to somehow affect with other plugin on WP_Query with particular custom post type via some hook, filter or action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did not get the time to test it yet. But it should be working.** The idea is to save the post ids and post types in wp_options. Then you can get those values and save them in an array. After that you compare them with current post and do the action that you want. You can put this in **functions.php**

```
function sr_excluded_users()
{
    global $post;
    global $wp_query;
    $exclusive_post_ids = array(); // List of post ids ( you can store it in wp options )
    $exclusive_post_types = array(); // List of custom post types ( you can store it in wp options )
    if( in_array( $post->ID, $exclusive_post_ids ) && in_array( $post->post_type, $exclusive_post_types ) )
    {        
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 ); 
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'sr_excluded_users' );
```

**Edit :** Function to remove posts from loop

```
function sr_excluded_users_loop($query) 
{
    $exclusive_post_ids = array(); // List of post ids ( you can store it in wp options )
    $query->set( 'post__not_in' , $exclusive_post_ids );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sr_excluded_users_loop' );
```

Comment: This is workable if I visit page, that's grat but how to remove from loop in list?

Comment: I think adding taxonomy is not necessary when we removing the posts directly. But if you need that too. see tax query parameter and use opertator not in

Comment: I want to give you +100 :) This action `pre_get_posts` I never use. Here I can manipulate with every loop? Tell me something, I also can define custom post type here?

Comment: yes you can. and you can add conditions if you want to work with a specific loop. check out these links https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts and https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: One help I need, is possible to use some other page insteand of 404 page? I know I can do with redirection but I don't want to redirect. Thanks!